# What is the best way to achieve unique Member functionality?

Tags: membership, private

im a developer that is somewhat new to wordpress. I have a client that is a wedding planner and wants to create a basic membership (paid) site where women can join and create checklists, budgets, seating charts ect for their wedding. All of this will be private to only them and used as a way to manage their wedding.

My question: Is there a  good way utilizing existing plugins (or a combination of them) to create a membership system where users can generate unique, private content.

It seems plugins like Wishlist member are only for selling gneral courses or content that is not user specific.

Is buddypress what im looking for?

Or am i better off building this from scratch?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!!

Comment: Please alter your question, plugins recommendations are off-topic [FAQ], and will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success in providing member functionality using the s2Member plugin. There are several solutions available so I would recommend researching "membership" plugins.

Comment: Answers on WPSE are expected to provide more then just  links/mention. Have a look at the [FAQ] , if you could provide more details or a more in depth answer. The question by the original poster can be considered off-topic since he is asking for a plugin.